# Spring XML databinding not in Controller

Tags: java, xml, spring, data-binding, controller

I want to move the Validation Logic from the Spring Controller to a ServletFilter and I would like to implement DataBinding in the ServletFilter so I can get automatic parsing of my XML data into my POJO and I can use BindingResult object in my filter.

Is that possible or I can take advantage of DataBinding and BindingResult only into my Controller?

Anyway, this is my controller's request mapping now:

```
@RequestMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
@ApiOperation(value="Verifica Ordine")
public Object listaVerificaOrdine(@Valid @RequestBody VerificaOrdineRequestModel requestModel, BindingResult result) throws RemoteException{
  if(result.hasErrors()){
    return "Errori: " + result.toString();
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to use Databinding and JSR-303 Validation outside the Controller by using the same libraries that our Spring Controller is using (but in the Controller they result "hidden" behind the Spring Framework). In particular:

1. for databinding from XML I use JAXB library
2. for JSR-303 validation I use javax.validation library.

Let's see how to di that:

```
try {
        Object model = JAXB.unmarshal(new StringReader(xmlString), classe);
        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
        Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> violations = validator.validate(model);

        for(ConstraintViolation violation : violations){
            responseError.append("Errore al percorso '" + violation.getPropertyPath() +"': ");
            responseError.append(" il valore trovato e' '" + violation.getInvalidValue() + "' ");
            responseError.append(", mentre il valore atteso deve rispettare il seguente criterio: '" + violation.getMessage() + "'. \n\n");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        responseError.append("Eccezione nel parsing dell'oggetto: " + e.toString() + ". Probabilmente il file XML di input non e' ben formato. Controllare i tag di apertura e di chiusura.  \n\n");
    }
```